# Is this question appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I was just about to search MathOnline, the project by Andrea Feretti, when I discovered the site is not up anymore. Is it appropriate to ask on Math Stackexchange if anyone knows if this website is down or has moved? I frequently make use of the sites class notes/book repositories, so I believe this question has some value.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems off-topic to me. You should try getting in touch with Andrea Ferretti directly.